# What does harder difficulty change?

Tags: child-of-light

In the game Child of Light by Ubisoft, what does selecting harder than normal difficulty level do exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It impacts combats: enemies are stronger but, more importantly, light orbs to recharge Igniculus won't spawn as fast and there won't be any HP/MP refill wishes.

Playing in hard mode makes the combats much more strategic.